# Replace two random characters by two other random characters in python

Tags: python, random

I need change 2 random characters (or more) in a string (x) by other two random characters in other diferent string (y), using Python, example strings:

```
x = 'ABCDEF'
y = 'GHIJK'
```

The possible solution would be:

> z=AB**I**D**G**F
>
> or
>
> z=A**K**CDE**H**

All changes completely random. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thank!

Comment: Homework? What did you try?

Comment: No homework, I need other alternatives

Comment: Alternatives to what? You didn't even mention your ideas of tackling this.

Comment: because I'm learning and I need to know if the experts do it the same way or they use cleaner and simples styles

Comment: The same way... if you really want to learn something, you would have shown us your approach. But well... you got your solution now...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the implementation.

**Code**

```
import random 
def swap_charcter(x,y):
    x_list = list(x)
    for i in random.sample(range(len(x_list)),2):
        x_list[i] = random.choice(y)
    return ''.join(x_list)
```

**Results**

```
In [1]: swap_charcter('ABCDEF','GHIJK')
Out[1]: 'ABIDEI'
In [2]: swap_charcter('ABCDEF','GHIJK')
Out[2]: 'ABCDHJ'
In [3]: swap_charcter('ABCDEF','GHIJK')
Out[3]: 'ABCDHI'
In [4]: swap_charcter('ABCDEF','GHIJK')
Out[4]: 'ABCIGF'
```

**Explanation**

1. `x_list = list(x)` This one for to assign the variables. I mean the replacing of `y` string elements. String not support index wise assignment.
2. `random.sample(range(len(x_list)),2)` This line implemented for to get the 2 random position of a string `x`.
3. `random.choice(y)` it will give a element in the string.
4. `''.join(x_list)` And joined the list to a resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

With `chain` and `sample`

```
from itertools import chain
from random import sample

x="ABCDEF"
y="ZYXWVU"

to_replace=3
print("".join(chain(sample(x,to_replace),sample(y,len(y)-to_replace))))
>>>FDAWXY
```

Comment: I think he is not looking for this. The just replace the character of `x` with using random choice from `y`.